# Wi-Fi is on but there is no connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Recently we got a new internet provider, which advertises 65 Mbps download, cable. Hence, we also got a new router: SmartRG model SR804n.

However, regardless of the amazing advertised speed, I have barely been able to connect to it at all. After countless calls to the provider I am fed up and not sure what to do.

The problem is some of the time, the internet works well; however, after 10 minutes of usage or so, the connection goes away. My MacBook Pro is still connected to the internet, however it says that there the server isn't found when trying to access the internet. Most of the time however, Skype is still functional with connection.

Also, when there is connection, I only get about 4 Mbps download and 8 Mbps upload (on speedtest.net website, which is no where close to 65 Mbps), which is around 150 mbps download in actual.

These are my current settings on my router:

[image]

Comment: You can have good wifi all day but if your provider isn't getting good signal to you it just won't work.   Also I'm not sure what the comment "which is around 150 Mbps download in actual"...65 is 65... Not 150

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that in actual I get 150 kbps* download speed when the Internet does work.